# cdkDropList how to bind/update data back to the array / source?

Tags: angular-material

In this simple [Stackbliz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kwcrnh?embed=1&file=src/app/cdk-drag-drop-custom-placeholder-example.html) based on Angular's CDK drop-drag list, I use drop() event to check values of array movies. How do I build a two-way binding to capture the data value change back to the array?

`[(cdkDropListData)]="movies"` won't do it.

Comment: I looked at your code, and the drop() function is modifying the "movies" array correctly. So it is essentially already a two way binding. What else are you looking for?

Comment: @MattNienow Updated Stackbliz above, thought I've created a new prj, it's not.

Comment: If you put the alert after the moveItemInArray call, then it will show correct results.

Comment: @MattNienow Nope, not happening.

Comment: I doubt if `[(cdkDropListData)]="movies"` will be effective, since the change is being made in javascript by `moveItemInArray`.

Comment: @Ackroydd same.

Comment: What's the same?

Comment: @Ackroydd Same thought

Comment: I'm curious as to why you changed the Angular sample to use `<input type="text" value="{{movie}}"/>` instead of `{{movie}}`?

Comment: @Ackroydd Else how do I provide an interface to edit the `movies` list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the DragDropModule import.

On the example site [components/src/components-examples/cdk/drag-drop](https://github.com/angular/components/tree/master/src/components-examples/cdk/drag-drop) it's in `index.ts`.

**main.ts**

```js
import './polyfills';
...    
import { DragDropModule } from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';

import {CdkDragDropCustomPlaceholderExample} from './app/cdk-drag-drop-custom-placeholder-example';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
    DragDropModule
  ],
  ...
})
export class AppModule {}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

**Binding input**

Based on comments, you want to two-way-bind the inputs.

The following needs to be added, if you are using drag and drop, or not.

- Banana-in-box on `<input>`
- A `trackBy` function in the ngFor expression
- Bind to `movies[i]` (it will not work binding to `movie`)

```html
<div cdkDropList class="example-list" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
  <div class="example-box" 
    *ngFor="let movie of movies; index as i; trackBy: trackByFn" 
    cdkDrag
  >
    <div class="example-custom-placeholder" *cdkDragPlaceholder></div>
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="movies[i]"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
export class CdkDragDropCustomPlaceholderExample {

  ...    
  drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
    alert(`Before drop update: ${this.movies}`);
    moveItemInArray(this.movies, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
    alert(`After drop update: ${this.movies}`);
  }

  trackByFn(index: number, item: String) {
    return index;
  }
}
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kwcrnh-kv4nlb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcdk-drag-drop-custom-placeholder-example.html)

I fire the alert before and after the drop update, take your pick.

Comment: Richard, although I doubt I did both as suggested. It didn't work. My code is a copy of the official sample from from **material**, nothing was removed, I just added `()` into `'[cdkDropListData]` and `alert()` to verify. The `import { DragDropModule } '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';` should be part of an existing module imported, may be `cdk-drag-drop-custom-placeholder-example` otherwise the drag-n-drop wouldn't work. About moving `alert()` after `drop()`, if it does update source then subsequent drag-n-drop will show previous changes.

Comment: Hey Jeb, I'm not sure what you have tried as your comment's not very clear to me, but it does work for me, provided you test in the correct place which is after the updating function.